# how log4j FileAppender is deprecated

Tags: java, log4j

can someone explain how `FileAppender` class is deprecated when its a superclass of `RollingFileAppender` and a subclass of `WriterAppender`?!

I tried looking for the reason why that class is deprecated, but couldn't find why.

Comment: Which version of log4j?

Comment: @Kayaman 1.2.17 which is the latest, [FileAppender has been deprecated and then removed](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter)

Comment: That's not what the javadoc says.

Comment: that's right, thanks. it's the support for java.io.Writer which is deprecated, but still it can be used to write on files

Answer (score 2):

The javadoc for the class (version 1.2) says the following (did you even look at the javadoc?)

```
Support for java.io.Writer and console appending has been deprecated and then removed. See the replacement solutions: WriterAppender and ConsoleAppender.
```

So the class as a whole isn't deprecated.

It just means that using `FileAppender` with a `Writer`, or with `System.out` or `System.err` is deprecated.

You can still use the class, The `FileAppender` class is not entirely deprecated, only parts of it (which have also been removed from the code).

Comment: I read the javadoc, thats where I knew about the deprecation, so since support for java.io.Writer has been removed how can one still write on a file using that class?